# Why my images repeats to occupy full area?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I wanted to display some text over an image. I do it successfully.
The problem is the image repeats itself to occupy all the available space.
But i want this image to be to not repeat.

My code to do it is  :

Css code :

```
.LabelCSSTop
{
   font-size:30px; font-style:normal; background-color :#0866c6;
}
.divination
{ 
  background-image: url(../images/icons/icon-event.png) ;  
}
```

And the .cshtml class is :

```
 <li class="odd">
   <a class=" divination">
     <label class="LabelCSSTop">@DateTime.Now.Day</label>
   </a>
```

**I just want this original image to have 10(which is day) on it (overlapping 17)**

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp, set to no-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.divination
{ 
  background-image: url(../images/icons/icon-event.png); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```